# Counting the number of occurrences of a 4 digit combination in a data series

Tags: xlsx

I have a series of 4 digit numbers, of which I would like to count the 4 digit combination which occurs the most.

Example data:

```
1234, 4321, 3578, 7654, etc.
```

In this data, I would like to count `1234` and `4321` as 2 occurrences as the order doesn't matter.  The numbers cannot repeat.

I know there are 24 combinations for each 4 digit number without repeating a number. I would like to be able to count all 24 variants as occurrences of the same number.

I have over 1000 4 digit numbers in my data series.

Can anyone help provide a solution please.

Regards
Michael